# google maps javascript roadmap view , setTilt() doesnt work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Anyone knows how to achieve the changeview ( tilt ) using javascript api ? the tilt is only mentioned in the android api :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views

eventhough the 45 degrees view is available in javascript api.

Comment: `map.getTilt()` and `map.setTilt()`?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're only using it with either **satellite** or **hybrid** map types. If you try to use it with the **roadmap** type, nothing will happen. Straight from the [Google Maps Javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference) for *setTilt()*:

> 45° imagery is only available for SATELLITE and HYBRID map types, within some locations, and at some zoom levels.

Answer (score 0):

For the web(client side) there are two ways:
1. When you initiate the map constructor mas the parameter tilt with the value 45
ex:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
                                                  zoom: zoomLevel, 
                                                  center: mapCoord,
                                                  tilt: 45
                                                });
```

2. After the map is iniated call the `setTitl()` method.
   ex:

> ```
> var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
>           center: {lat: 36.964, lng: -122.015},
>           zoom: 18,
>           mapTypeId: 'satellite'
>         });
> map.setTilt(45);
> ```

Conclusion:

To see the tilt button you have to change your map to satellite. You can't see the tilt button? That is because Google doesn't have that option for your map area. Now zoom out from and go over Paris. If you can see the tilt button is because Paris has the 45 deg angle view option.